# Read the serial port

Tags: python, arduino

I dont seem to get the proper reading Id like from my serial.write/read. What do I do wrong?
After one turn in the loop, I would like to have another A00 output, but instead I get D13HIGH, as you can see below.

```
import serial
from time import sleep
import math

port = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
baud = 9600

ser = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baud)

sleep(0.2)

count = 0

while count < 20:
    ser.write('a--A00READ--')
    sleep(0.2)
    reply = ser.read(12)
    print(reply)
    adc = reply[7:]
    adc = adc.strip('-')
    adc = int(adc)
    volts = (adc / 1023.0 * 5.0)
    ser.write('a--D13HIGH--')
    count += 1

ser.close()
```

Output:

```
>>> 
a--A00+487--
a--D13HIGH--

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/serialcom.py", line 21, in <module>
    adc = int(adc)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'IGH'
>>>
```

Comment: adc=int(adc, 16) for a start

Comment: Thank you for your input! My issue is not the base 10 though, the issue is that I dont get a new reading from A00 after one loop, it sticks with "a--D13HIGH--", by some reason I cant figure out why!

Comment: @Martik sorry, but... I don't believe in magic, neither in telepathy. And I don't think anybody here can directly read your mind. So, since obviously you are making python and arduino communicate, and since quite obviously the problem is in the interaction between the two, please write a complete question and POST THE ARDUINO CODE